# CSV File header extend python

Tags: python, csv

I am looking for a way to extend a header of a CSV file. 
I have the file header in a dictionary (`dict1`) and another dictionary (`dict2`) with keys that some are duplicates of `dict1` and would like to extend the header in the file.

I was told there is something like `csv.header.extend()` but not sure how it works and couldn't find examples.

My CSV looks like:

```
V,T1,T2,T3,T4 
U1,a,b,c,d
U2,q,w,e,r
```

Lets say `dict2` is

```
dict2 = {'V': 'U3', 'T1': 'p', 'T2': 'o', 'T5': 'z'}
```

The CSV would come out like this:

```
V,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5
U1,a,b,c,d,
U2,q,w,e,r,
U3,p,o,,,z
```

Anyone knows how this would work?

Comment: Check out collections.defaultdict(str).  Also check out dict1.update(dict2).  HTH

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [`csv.DictWriter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which uses all fields:

```
fieldnames = ['V','T1','T2','T3','T4','T5']
with open(...) as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
```

You can then write each row by passing a dictionary that contains the values of that row:

```
for my_dict in my_dicts:
    writer.writerow(my_dict)
```

So the steps to take are:

- Compute a list that contains the headers of both files (i.e., merge `['V','T1','T2','T3','T4']` of the existing file with other headers that you may have, such as `'T5'`).
- Compute dictionaries per row that contain a value for each of the headers. For example, your `dict2` would need to become: `dict2 = {'V': 'U3', 'T1': 'p', 'T2': 'o', 'T5': 'z', 'T3': '', 'T4': ''}`.
- After that you can use the above code to create the `DictWriter` with all the possible fields in the output file and you can write each of the output rows by passing them as dictionaries.